# Error declaring the click event pragmatically using onClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I am trying to set up a button that upon being clicked, calls a function in a subclass of View that I have created.  But even though I am following the Android documentation exactly as it is written on the help pages, I keep getting an error.

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

And here is the class that contains the function I am trying to access, along with the piece of code that attempts to tie a button in the layout to the function that I am trying to run (it clears a list):

```
public class Drawing extends View implements OnTouchListener{

private ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();

Button resetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        eraseLines();
    }
});


public Drawing(Context context, AttributeSet xmlAttributes){
    super(context, xmlAttributes);
    setOnTouchListener(this);   
}


public void eraseLines(){
    lines.clear();
}
```

What am I doing wrong that keeps me from being able to simply have the button run the eraseLines() function in the class Drawing?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post the logcat?

Comment: does application go into onCLick() function? May be error: you implement Ontouchlistener instead of onclick listener?

Comment: Do you actually implement OnTouchListener in your **Drawing**  class ? Have you overridden the method _onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)_ ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your view's layout is not properly inflated when yout retrieve your button, and thus its reference might be null.

You should do :

```
public class Drawing extends View implements OnTouchListener{{

  private ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();

  public Drawing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    // Inflate layout prior to retrieving the button
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_drawing_layout, this, true);

    // Assuming 'button2' id exists in 'your_drawing_layout'
    Button resetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v){
          eraseLines();
      }
    });

  }

  public void eraseLines(){
    lines.clear();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
    // Implementation of onTouch
  }
}
```